# Winston outputs json instead of formatted string

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, npm, winston

I have set up a simple winston logger in my app like this:

```
function logger(success, msg) {
    let now = new Date().toUTCString()
    let logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.File)({ 
                filename: 'log.log',
                timestamp: function() {
                    return new Date().toUTCString();
                },
                formatter: function(options) {
                    return `>>>>>>>>>> ${options.timestamp()} - ${options.level.toUpperCase} - ${options.message}`;
                }
            })
        ]
    });

    if (success) {
        logger.log('info', msg)
    } else {
        logger.log('error', msg)
    }
}
```

But instead of logging the formatted string, it outputs the following:

> `{"level":"error","message":"Nothing to upload","timestamp":"Mon, 23 Apr 2018 13:53:01 GMT"}`

Ideas? Am I missing something? (Of course I am)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find out in winston documentation for [File](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#file-transport) you can set property `json` to false if you don't want information in file to be JSON objects. By **default** this property is `true`.

> json: If true, messages will be logged as JSON (default true).

Could you try to change your code like this:

```
function logger(success, msg) {
    let now = new Date().toUTCString()
    let logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.File)({ 
                filename: 'log.log',
                timestamp: function() {
                    return new Date().toUTCString();
                },
                json: false,
                formatter: function(options) {
                    return `>>>>>>>>>> ${options.timestamp()} - ${options.level.toUpperCase} - ${options.message}`;
                }
            })
        ]
    });

    if (success) {
        logger.log('info', msg)
    } else {
        logger.log('error', msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't saw that one. Thank you!

Comment: this works for `transports.File`, is there a similar option for `transports.Console`?